# Topojson map not rendering in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg, topojson

Attempting to follow this simple map tutorial here : https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Using New York map data found on nyc's open data page(I'm using the Boro Boundries json and the NHood Names json)

I've converted the json successfully so I'm working with [this json](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f8e319ffb3ba26009cfd74d797e7967d)

When I make it to step 2 of this tutorial the svg doesn't seem to render, and I cannot figure out why. I can see the "path" object it creates when I open up the inspector, but its of size (0, 0). I'm running this locally with MAMP  by the way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var width = 960,
            height = 1160;

        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .scale(500)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);


        var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("fill", "black");


        d3.json("ny.json", function(error, ny) {
          var nyhood = topojson.feature(ny, ny.objects.nyhood);
          svg.append("path")
              .datum(nyhood)
              .attr("d", path);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing but I also tried the part of the tutorial that uses Albers instead of Mercator and the only result was that the  object was populated with the path data, and the size of the path on the page was a lot bigger, but still no svg was rendered.

Comment: Looking at your json data, those are not coordinates. Max range of latitude is -90,+90, max range of longitude is -180,180. Your coordinates are in the thousands.

Comment: That's correct for a TopoJSON. TopoJSON "uses fixed-precision delta-encoding for integer coordinates rather than floats". The problem *is* the TopoJSON, though, but not because of the coordinates.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado So should I try regenerating my TopoJson then? Maybe just with one dataset rather than two?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado that was it! something seems to be rendering.. even though its currently one giant blob... progress haha thank you for pointing it out